# Why lists cannot be used with wx.BoxSizer?

Tags: python, list, wxpython, wxwidgets

I wanted to use lists made by wx.BoxSizer elements to make my code more readable and easier to manage but for some reason wxpython cannot use this kind of lists.

So here I wrote a code that works well without using the lists:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        ts = [wx.StaticText(self, -1, str(i)) for i in range(3)]
        ct  = [wx.TextCtrl(self, -1) for i in range(3)]

        hsizer1.Add(ts[0], 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer2.Add(ts[1], 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer3.Add(ts[2], 1, wx.EXPAND)

        hsizer1.Add(ct[0], 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer2.Add(ct[1], 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer3.Add(ct[2], 1, wx.EXPAND)



        vsizer.Add(hsizer1, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vsizer.Add(hsizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vsizer.Add(hsizer3, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetSizer(vsizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        MyPanel(self)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

With this code you'll obtain the desired layout. 
But if I use lists and cycles everything goes wrong:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hsizer1 = [wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)]*3
        ts = [wx.StaticText(self, -1, str(i)) for i in range(3)]
        ct = [wx.TextCtrl(self, -1) for i in range(3)]

        for i in range(3):
            hsizer1[i].Add(ts[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)
            hsizer1[i].Add(ct[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)


        for i in hsizer1:
            vsizer.Add(i, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.SetSizer(vsizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        MyPanel(self)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see they should produce the very same output but the don't. My question then is: why lists cannot be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you have the list hsizer1, which contains the same object 3 times. So it does not quite matter if you add to hsizer[0], hsizer[1] or hsizer[2], you are always adding into the same sizer. To fix it:

```
hsizer1 = [wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) for i in range(3)]
```

Or you could:

```
for i in range(3):
    hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    hsizer.Add(ts[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)
    hsizer.Add(ct[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)
    vsizer.Add(hsizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
```